# black screen on windows 8 after login + PC auto restarts when trying to F8

Tags: windows-8

I was getting annoyed by my mouse kind of failing during a game, so I decided to remove the USB wireless receiver and plug it back on. My computer instantly crashed. After rebooting it by the reset button, I log in and I get a black screen. I have access to task manager and I even tried to execute explorer.exe manually (like I used to do on WinXP) no success. Dozens of restart and the problem won't go away. I tried to press F8 during boot to try and repair windows 8, but when I press F8, the built-in sound makes a small noise and the computer crashes and instantly restarts.
Any suggestions? Without F8 I can't do anything.

Thanks in advance.
(Posting from a mobile, not really easy to choose tags)

Comment: It sounds like you suffered a hardware failure likely the hdd.  The plugging the mouse in wasn't the cause though.  It sounds like you were already having I/O problems before you removed and plugged the mouse back in.

Answer (score 0):

Since your device still boots, and Windows lets you log in, I do not believe you've suffered from hardware failure. The issue you're having seems to be a corrupt user profile setting.

I'd recommending attempting these steps. If successful, Windows should fix the issue for you.

1. Open and Administrator Command Prompt
   1) Press `Ctrl + Shift + Esc` to open the Task Manager.
   2) Choose `File > Run new task` from the menu
   3) Check the `Create this task with administrative privileges.` check box
   4) Type in `cmd` in the text area and hit `OK`
2. Run a System File Check by typing this into the Command Prompt window: `sfc /scannow` You must include the space and the `/`.

Windows will check all the system files, such as those it appears you're having issues with, and attempt to fix them automatically.

If you're unable to access the command prompt, then your computer may require a physical Windows 8.1 installation disc. Booting from the disc will allow you to repair your Windows 8 installation.